# Google Analytics API returns 0 value for some websites

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I have a Google Analytics account where multiple companies have shared their website with me. Now trying to get visitors/sessions/hits data from those websites using the API. It works perfectly fine for 2 websites, but 4 others aren't returning any data. It's a consistent problem and it doesn't matter whether I select the past week, or a week in the past. I'm also not getting any error, or message, just a 0 for all 3 dimensions. This is the exact response I'm getting:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "data": {
        "isDataGolden": true,
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "0",
              "0",
              "0"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:segment",
          "ga:pagePath",
          "ga:date"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "type": "INTEGER",
              "name": "ga:users"
            },
            {
              "type": "INTEGER",
              "name": "ga:sessions"
            },
            {
              "type": "INTEGER",
              "name": "ga:hits"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update:** I selected a week 6 years back when the website got ~400 visitors a day, instead of the ~10k it is getting to day, and it does seem to work now. Is there a way to make it work with large number of visitors as well? I'm just using the `analytics.reports().batchGet` function of the Python SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using `'operator': 'PARTIAL'` instead of `'operator': 'EXACT'`.